# How can I find good tutorial for building firefox add-ons on latest version of firefox 30.0?

Tags: firefox-addon

I have tried to use internet tutorials Hello World examples for building firefox add-ons by XUL but all examples gives me corrupt add-on when I try to install into firefox as it is.

Does anyone have good working .xpi examples or tutorial?

Comment: Those hello world examples, while not great, usually work. [Did you make sure you zipped correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23690580/484441)? What have you tried? What is the specific error?

Comment: The error message is: "This add-on couldn't be installed because it appears to be corrupt."

Comment: Yeah, that sound very much like incorrect zipping (see my previous link). Otherwise you'll need to post your actual code if you want help figuring out what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was in the provided link at the following point: "Quite often people actually zip up the outer folder. I.e. the resulting zip (.xpi) then contains /some-addon-folder/install.rdf instead of just /install.rdf. Make sure to not zip the outer folder, just the files and subfolders within.". Please make it answer.

Comment: I have a bunch of templates on my gist site. What are you trying to make an addon of? read the part explaining my gist naming scheme at noitidart.github.io and then go my gist pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, as we figured out together, the XPI file was incorrectly zipped.

It did not include the XPI items directly as it should have, but within a subfolder in the zip.

Correct zipping of XPI files is further [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23690580/484441).